# REST API Service : should be Bound or IntentService?

Tags: android, service

If we define an Service to handle our REST API

Should this service be bound or IntentService ?

As we need to access it from many activities and need it to hold current Client-Server state attributes, I think we should choose the Bound Service, but am I right?

**Summary**
So finally I decided to combine Singleton and Sync Adapter models. Sync Adapter for large datasets and Singleton for quering non-data calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try using a `SyncAdapter`?
Take a look at [this](http://naked-code.blogspot.com/2011/05/revenge-of-syncadapter-synchronizing.html) blog post.

Comment: Interesting, but is it really a good idea to let user stop synchronizing the data? As the application is needed to have the latest data possible, or the most of functions can't be used.

Comment: Using a `SyncAdapter` doesn't mean you can't force an update.

Comment: Although you answered as last of all, your answer brought me most info I needed. Thanks

Comment: @MarekSebera: np. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

A bound service would be the best choice if you need to maintain state. IntentService is more for a worker queue type of invocation, where the service starts, does some work and then stops when there's no more work.

Answer (score 1):

The only advatage of using a Service instead of a singleton is that if your process has a started Service, the process is less likely to be killed by the OS (see this answer - [Android: When to use Service vs Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567667/android-when-to-use-service-vs-singleton)).

So I would just use a singleton instead of a Service. And perhaps start a dummy Service as a way of telling the OS that you want to stay in memory as long as possible. When you are ok with your process being killed, stop the dummy Service.

Comment: Yes, possible. Can we put this singleton into an different Thread? To avoid setting UI non-responding.

Comment: Of course, you should start a new Thread on your singleton (you would have to do this in a Service too).