# How to manage socket/http post while screen is rotating on android?

Tags: android, sockets, rotation

I have a form where a user fills and hits OK button to submit data to remote site over HTTP.

Right after hitting OK button, when user rotates the screen, socket is shut down automatically.

Should i define connection as static? If so, everything is going to be static in other classes too in similar behaviours... This might not be the right way...

How to manage this process on Android OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the activity is restarted on rotate the device, this restart can happens in some more situations. (You can check in [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) under, *Configuration Changes* section

One given way to solve your problem is the user of [android services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). You create a `Service`, that runs independently from your activity.

As suggested by @SimonSays, you can implement singleton class. The implementation of a singleton is easier than that of a service, you can check the pros of each approach on the SO post below:

[Android: When to use Service vs Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567667/android-when-to-use-service-vs-singleton)

Answer (score 1):

I would move all the connection logic to a separate class that uses the singleton pattern.